# Summing a column in Excel based on a another value falling between each rows 2 adjacent cells

Tags: excel

I have an excel spreadsheet that will do analysis on direct debits on a selection of accounts,
I have a lookup sheet `"Sheet2"` as shown in the picture which will contain the info I need.

The table I am interested in has 3 columns i am interested in, `amount` and a `to and from` date.

On `Sheet1` `B13` I want to do a `=sum()` on `Sheet2:D5:D:100`, but only add it to the total IF the date in `B1` is in the range.

I can sum the columns fine, and even sum one row based on the date using `-sumifs()`, but don't know where to start with this issue. I assume I would need to use a count() or something?

I'm not necessarily looking for a straight answer, but a rough explanation to the autocalc so I can do this sort of thing easily in the future!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd be best off using an array formula mixed with your sum. Something like

```
=SUM((B1>Sheet2!$D$5:$D$100)*(B1<Sheet2!$E$5:$E$100)*Sheet2!$C$5:$C$100)
```

Now what is going on here is happening in several parts:

1. The first set of inner brackets (B1>Sheet2!$D$5:$D$100) checks that that date in B1 is greater than the first date in your other sheet. This evaluates as 1 for true, 0 for false.
2. The second set of inner brackets (B1

   These 1 or 0 values multiplied are only a 1 if *both conditions are true*. So the third part comes in to play when the dates align, and the sum is calculated.

   This formula is an array formula, since each of these operations are applied to *every row within your defined ranges*

To enter an array formula in Excel you must enter the formula with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER. Curly brackets { } will appear around the formula. It will look something like

```
{=SUM((B1>Sheet2!$D$5:$D$100)*(B1<Sheet2!$E$5:$E$100)*Sheet2!$C$5:$C$100)}
```

if it has worked. Just comment if you can't quite get it and I'll help you out.

Answer (score 2):

Plain old sumifs?

```
    A       B           C
1       2013-03-14  
2   6   2013-01-01  2013-01-02
3   8   2013-03-12  2013-03-23
4   5   2013-05-21  2013-06-01
    =SUMIFS(A2:A4;B2:B4;CONCATENATE("<=";B1);C2:C4;CONCATENATE(">=";B1))
```

Comment: beat me to it... you don't need `CONCATENATE`, a simple `&` will join items together: e.g. `CONCATENATE("<=";B1)` will become `"<="&B1`

Comment: also depending on your region & language setting list separator, you might need to use `,` instead of `;`

Comment: ... in which case sumifs is spelled differently

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have several dates you are looking to run through this sum, (from the first part of C1 there), I would set it up in one of three ways.

Use an extra sheet with extra columns where the dateLowerBound < date < dateUpperBound is calculated for each date you have in sheet1, and using `SUMIF` with that extra column as the key.

Use `DSUM` which can support compound criteria but has a syntax that seems to always make me angry for considering using `DSUM`.

Write a VB macro (assuming that the structure of the sheet is reasonable static, and that there are well defined points where it would make sense to re-calculate a Total, you could hook it to the onChanged event of the date cells and / or to the Sheet2 data table area.

Comment: VB may be a good approach.
There will only be the one date per calculation:  `B13` will be the sum of all rows in sheet2 where the date in `B1` is between the two dates in columns `D` and `E` in sheet2.
`C1` will use `C13, `D1 will use D13` and so on.